# Using multiple <script> tags to prevent errors

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I recently took a job at a new company and they have a policy of using a new `<script>` tag for each new Javascript function, when I asked about it they said it's to prevent errors from breaking the entire page.

It does seem to prevent an exception from breaking all of the other Javascript, but I've never seen it before. Is this a common practice, is there any issues with doing it that way?

Comment: It's not common practice. It sounds like they're using that as a crutch against writing better code. Littering your page with multiple `script` elements is not encouraged as it simply adds more clutter, making the page harder to read and visually debug. Additionally, depending on how much code we are talking about, it could impact the file download time.

Comment: I would prefer to create as lower as possible tags in the HTML otherwise client engine takes time in processing the tags and execution of the script.

Comment: This is one of those things that "works, but..." If a script fails to define a function for some reason, then another script trying to access that function will break in turn. It is sensible for errors in JavaScript to be fatal, because they are rarely recoverable without fixing the original problem, which is a lot easier when there's only one script breaking; one error message.

Comment: I suppose that's a way to prevent errors. Like Scott Marcus said, it's not common, and it is indeed pretty poor. Rather than preventing errors by putting multiple script elements in a page, prevent errors by debugging the errors and fixing them. That's the best method. Good code doesn't need a million script elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys, this reflects what I was taught and practice as well, but I wanted to make sure before I started doing things different than the previous developers here.

Comment: But why does the error in one script tag js doesn't block execution of next script tag?